# Restore site collection from higher database version to lower database version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, backup, restore

I have a development SP Farm (along with Project Server) with following database version:

> Configuration database version: 16.0.4534.1000

UAT SP Farm with following database version:

> Configuration database version: 16.0.4600.1001

UAT SP Farm (only project server) with following database version:

> Configuration database version: 16.0.4744.1000

Can I restore the site collections of UAT SP Farm into Development farm?

Or do i have to upgrade the Development Farm? If yes, should I upgrade it to DB version **16.0.4744.1000** ?

Server in dev as well as UAT are Windows Server 2012.

Any help and best practises in order to achieve above scenario is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restore site collection from a higher version, you may meet an error about "Schema version does not match...". For this issue, I suggest you upgrade your development environment to 16.0.4744.1000. Then restore site collections.

In addition, there is a blog about restoring site collections from higher version without installing CU, you can have a try:
[How to restore site collection from higher Sharepoint version](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-restore-site-collection-from.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing this with following steps:

- Make the backup of the Content database in UAT environment
- Restore the database to the Dev database environment
- Connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio
- Open the table `Versions` in edit mode and change the value in the `Version` column to `16.0.4534.1000` (if there are multiple rows there, you should change the value for the row with the largest value of `Id` column)
- After this step the database should be ready and you can do the standard procedure ([mount the content database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/attach-or-detach-content-databases))

Comment: Appreciate you response. 
But we do not access to the database in UAT environment. 
Is there any other solution?

Comment: Please do not edit any SharePoint Database. You will lose Support on the entire Farm. Even if it is Development, we shouldn‘t give Bad-practise advise here.